# How do I catch a specific exception thrown by the Laravel 5.6 Queue's failed method?

Tags: laravel

My `handler()` throws a SalesforceException. I want to watch that and log the particular error message from the it, using the `failed()` method on the Queue in Laravel 5.6.  If I do the below, I am getting the error:

**Error**

```
[2018-04-17 00:18:12] local.ERROR: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Listeners\SyncNewsletterSignupToSalesforce::failed() must be an instance of Exception, instance of App\Events\NewsletterSignup given {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\\Listeners\\SyncNewsletterSignupToSalesforce::failed() must be an instance of Exception, instance of App\\Events\\NewsletterSignup ...
```

**Code**

```
  public function failed(Exception $e)
    {
        try {

        } catch(SalesforceException $e)
        {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            logger($responseBodyAsString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `must be an instance of Exception` -- could you share the one that raises the exception? does `SalesforceException` actually extend [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a listener in your AppServiceProvider to listen for failed jobs from the queue:

```
public function boot() {
     Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
        // $event->connectionName
        // $event->job 
        // $event->exception

        // check for the specific exception type
        if ($event->exception instanceof SalesforceException) {
             // do something
        }
     }); 
}
```

More here on [failed job events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#failed-job-events).

Comment: I actually setup a similar thing in `Handler.php`. Yours is a better solution. Thanks